# Por qué mi programa no me permite comparar estos dos arreglos de caracteres?

Tags: c++

En mi programa hay una función que toma un string que debe contener varios días separados por espacios, esta función devuelve el número de días que hay en dicho string. Mi problema está en que cuando llega al if dentro del ciclo for no realiza la comparación adecuadamente y devuelve un error. Aún no he podido averiguar por qué. Debajo dejo mi código.

```
int num_days(string days)
{
    int num_days;

    int i;

    for(i =0; i < days.size(); i++)
        {
            if((days.at(i)).compare(" ") == 0)
                {
                    num_days++;
                }
        }

    return num_days;
}
```

Comment: ¿ Mensaje de error **exacto** que recibes ?

Comment: Esto parece .net mas que c++ nativo. ¿me equivoco?

Comment: Esto no  compila

Answer (score 2):

Hay un problema y es que tienes la variable `num_days` no inicializada. Iníciala a 0. Además, para comparar caracteres no necesitas la función compare. De tal manera tu código funcional queda así:

```
  int num_days(string days) {
    int num_days=0;

    for(int i=0; i < days.size(); i++) {
            if(days.at(i) == ' ') {
                    num_days++;
                }
        }

    return num_days;
}
```

Comment: Después de compilarlo he descubierto que contenía otro error en la funcion compare. Gracias @Trauma

Comment: Eso ya es otra cosa. Ahora sí :-)